# window.history.pushState issue on IE

Tags: jquery, history.js, html5-history

I am using `jQueryUI Auto-complete` on my site along with it is the `window.history.pushState` which changes the browser-url without refreshing the page. It perfectly works on `Chrome` and `Mozilla` but unfortunately it does not work the way I wanted it to work on `Internet Explorer 9`. Here's the situation, using `jQueryUI Auto-complete` I can search for regions, counties and zips thru the `<input />` tag on my page. Then if I clicked any of the suggested results of the auto-complete, using `window.history.pushState` the browser-url changes to from `www.example.com/sites` to `www.example.com/sites/selected_region` without refreshing the page. Now as what I have said, it works on `Chrome` and `Mozilla` but it fails on `IE9`, because what happens is that when I clicked any of the suggested results of the `jQueryUI Auto-complete`, it neither changes the browser-url nor closes the list of suggestions. It definitely does not support `window.histoty.pushState`. So I searched and found a solution that might worked using `history.js`. I just followed the instructions to upload it on my server and include the `history.js` files but it turns out it conflicts with my other `.js` files being used. How would I fix this? Thanks in advance.

**PS:** Here's how I use `window.history.pushState`

```
$( "#find" ).autocomplete({
minLength: 1,
source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(locations, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        },
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.value );
    return false;
},
appendTo: "#results",
open: function(){
    var position = $("#results").position(),
                    left = position.left, top = position.top;

            $("#results > ul").css({left: (left + 15) + "px",
                                                    top: (top + 30) + "px", width: (206) + "px" });
},

select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $(":header.title").html(ui.item.value);

    var base = '/stats/';
    var url = base + ui.item.href;
    var label_name = ui.item.value;
    document.title = "Statistics for " + label_name + "| ASI";
    window.history.pushState({"url":url}, document.title, url);
    return false;
}
});
```

Please feel free to correct me in any way possible. Cheers.

Comment: can you post the conflict you get? you should use `History.pushState()` function instead of `window.history.pushState()` if you are using History.js plugin

Comment: @Eru, does `History.pushState()` works just the same as `window.history.pushState()` ? Or what will be the fix if I will go back to what I have previously used, just using `window.history.pushState()` and exclude using `history.js`, what will be my fix to make it work on `IE9` ?

Comment: IE does not support html5 history api. You have to use `history.js` plugin or similar to support it. It works very similar.