# Changing URL not working in IE

Tags: ajax, html, internet-explorer, jquery

I need to change the directory in the URL each time I'm loading a new page with AJAX. Right now it's working in Chrome & FF but not in IE.

```
$('a[data-link="inner"]').live('click', function (e) {
    pageToLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    loadContent(pageToLoad);
    window.history.pushState("","" , pageToLoad);
    e.preventDefault();
}

var loadContent = function (url) {
    $('.content').load(url + '.html');      
};
```

Does anyone know how to get this working in IE 9,8,7 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497958/window-history-pushstate-issue-on-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497958/window-history-pushstate-issue-on-ie)

Comment: See also [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705241/ie-history-push-state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705241/ie-history-push-state)

Comment: IE does'nt have support for the history API, Google would have told you that by the time you finished writing the first line in your question ?